# How can we re-enable access to the YouTube Data API?

Tags: api, quota

We have a product that pulls from the YouTube Data API but have been blocked. Response from the api is that we've exceeded our quota but our account hasn't had any activity in a year.

Encountered 403 Forbidden with reason "quotaExceeded"

Is there someone to speak with to see how about getting access restored?

Thanks
Suzy

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow,Please check (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)how to ask a good question. Your question is currently missing too much information to be able to help you

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question needs to be directed directly to YouTube. Asking on SO is off-topic because you're asking us for recommendations on how to deal with YouTube, in what is possibly not even a coding problem. See "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and their linked pages.